# Adding PdfDiv to Paragraph

Tags: java, pdf, itext, xmlworker

It's the topic connected with [List items in table cell are not formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318994/list-items-in-table-cell-wrongly-formatted). I'm using XmlWorker to process HTML output from formattable control (dijit/Editor from Dojo). There are some blocks (when you use centering or margin formatters) like that:

```
<div>
    <p align="center"><font size="5"><b>&nbsp;<font color="#32cd32">My centered Para</font></b></font><font color="#32cd32">&nbsp;</font></p>
</div>
```

However, when I add them to the `Paragraph` that is added to the Table like here:

```
    PdfPCell htmlCell = new PdfPCell();
    htmlCell.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(213, 226, 187));
    htmlCell.addElement(html2Para(html));
    htmlCell.setPaddingBottom(5);
    htmlCell.setPaddingLeft(5);
    table.addCell(htmlCell);

private Paragraph html2para(String html) {
    final Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
    try {
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(new ElementHandler() {
            @Override
            public void add(Writable wri) {
                if (wri instanceof WritableElement) {
                    List<Element> elems = ((WritableElement) wri).elements();
                    for (Element elem : elems) {
                        para.add(elem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new StringReader(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(html)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return para;
}
```

Everything that is inside the `Element` that is the instance of `PdfDiv` is not visible.

So, when I meet the PdfDiv, I add its content:

```
private void addElem2para(Element elem, Paragraph target) {
    if (elem instanceof PdfDiv) {
        for (Element inside : ((PdfDiv)elem).getContent()) {
            addElem2para(inside, target);
        }
    } else {
        target.add(elem);
    }
}
```

However, now that formatting like centering or margin that were the properties of the `PdfDiv` are 'lost'.

How should one deal with the `PdfDiv` elements from XmlWorker?

I'm using iText and XmlWorker in version 5.5.2

Answer (score 2):

(I think) I understand your question, but I don't understand your code.

The [`ParseHtml`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtml) example shows how I interpreted your question:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<div>\n<p align=\"center\">");
sb.append("<font size=\"5\">");
sb.append("<b>&nbsp;<font color=\"#32cd32\">My centered Para</font></b>");
sb.append("</font>");
sb.append("<font color=\"#32cd32\">&nbsp;</font>");
sb.append("</p>\n</div>");

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
ElementList list = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(sb.toString(), null);
for (Element element : list) {
    cell.addElement(element);
}
table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
```

You have some HTML (I stored your HTML snippet in `sb`) that you want to parse into a series of iText objects to be added to a table cell.

This is the result of this operation:

[image: Screen shot]

That looks pretty much the way I expected.

Comment: XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList what version of library is that? I don't see that method in my 5.5.2 version. I've added version to my question.

Comment: Version 5.5.4. I added that convenience method because I was getting tired to copy/paste the same code sequence over and over in my answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: OK I've tested it. It much improves processing of HTML and placing it in stand-alone paragraph, but still, if I add the paragraph to the table, I must filter out the PdfDivs, because their content doesn't show up.

Comment: Strange... I can't reproduce this. Maybe it's because I'm using a SNAPSHOT of version 5.5.5.

Comment: I've tested (with 5.5.4) - If I add PdfDiv to PdfCell directly, it's rendered. But if I add Paragraph with PdfDiv inside, it's not rendered. The problem is, that with the dirty HTML output from Dojo, there are many divs embedded within other elements....

Comment: @VikasVats Which version of iText are you using? As shown in my example, I can't reproduce the issue. How did you get that issue?

Comment: I am using itext 5.5.6 with xmlworker 5.5.6. I used addElem2para() method which works for me. But your solution is not working. I get empty elementList from XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(sb.toString(), null);

Comment: @VikasVats Please don't expect someone to be able to solve your problem if you don't provide more info. You are hijacking an answer to a different question. If you have a problem, create a new question.