# iTextSharp - Paragraph Line-Height

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, typography

I'm currently working on a PDF but I am facing issues trying to increase the line-height of a `Paragraph`, this is the code that I have now:

```
var tempTable = new PdfPTable(1);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("My Account", GetInformationalTitle()));
cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
tempTable.AddCell(cell);

cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("http://www.google.com/", GetInformationalOblique()));
cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
tempTable.AddCell(cell);

var para = new Paragraph("Login to 'My Account' to access detailed information about this order. " +
"You can also change your email address, payment settings, print invoices & much more.", GetInformationalContent());
 para.SetLeading(0f, 2f);

 cell = new PdfPCell(para);
 cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
 tempTable.AddCell(cell);
```

As you can see from above, I'm trying to increase the line-height of `para`, I've tried `para.SetLeading(0f, 2f)` but it is still not increasing the line-height or leading, as it is called.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate of [iText: maintain identing if paragraph takes new line in PdfPCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073190/itext-maintain-identing-if-paragraph-takes-new-line-in-pdfpcell), but the answer is the same: you are adding the `Paragraph` in *text mode* instead of adding it in *composite mode*. In your case, the leading of the `PdfPCell` gets preference over the leading of the `Paragraph` (as you have noticed that leading is ignored in *text mode*).

Comment: Awesome! I've fixed it by using `AddElement(para)` instead of initializing it in the constructor. You might want to post it in an answer so I can mark it as answered, once again, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding `para` in *text mode* instead of adding it in *composite mode*. Text mode means that the leading of the `PdfPCell` will get preference over the leading defined for the `Paragraph`. With composite mode, it's the other way around.

You can fix this with a small change:

```
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(para);
tempTable.AddCell(cell);
```

Using the `addElement()` method makes `cell` switch from text mode to composite mode.

Comment: The only correct answer over the net, you saved me hours man 